# Request to check all array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a problem with MongoDB syntax.
I have two documents:
alley(the "tree" field is the ID of the tree):

```
 {
        "_id": {"$oid": "62572d82cc40164fef7f1a56"},
        "name": "good alley",
        "tree": [
          {"$oid": "626976eb4b93122bc617d701"},
          {"$oid": "626976eb4b93122bc617d702"}
        ]
      },
```

.......
tree:

```
{
            "_id": {"$oid": "626976eb4b93122bc617d701"},
            "dateInstall": {"$date": "2021-02-27T00:00:00.000Z"},
            "species": [
              {"$oid": "62585a63edfc726a4ff24fb8"}
            ]
          },
```

.......

I need to write a query "an alley where trees were not planted last year"
My Code

```
db.alley.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "tree",
            localField: "tree",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "tree"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {{$not:{$and:[
                    {"tree.dateInstall": {$gt: new ISODate("2020-12-31")}},
                    {"tree.dateInstall": {$lt: new ISODate("2022-01-01")}}
                    ]
            }}}
    }
]);
```

Comment: tree will be an array after the lookup, you can 1)use $filter to keep only the trees that match those dates,and the unwind if you want OR 2)use unwind and and match, and group if you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first `$unwind` trees in alleys so you can properly `$lookup` the trees in tree collection. Use `pipeline` inside lookup to query only trees planted last year. Finally `$group` trees into alleys again and use `$match` to filter out those alleys without trees.

```
db.getCollection("alley").aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$tree",
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
        from: "tree",
        let: { tree: "$tree" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  { $eq: [ "$$tree", "$_id" ] },
                  { $gt: [ "$dateInstall", new ISODate("2020-12-31") ] },
                  { $lt: [ "$dateInstall", new ISODate("2022-01-01") ] },
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        localField: "tree",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "tree"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { id: "$_id", name: "$name" },
      trees: { $addToSet: { $first: "$tree" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      trees: { $size: 0 }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please suggest a course or resource for structured learning of this language

Comment: @34trehtbgdw45rtb I was using just MongoDB official docs. :-) You can simply go through individual operators (`$match`, `$group`) etc. Usually I read only the examples section and understand how it works.